# Java YTApi LiveChatMessage (v 3)

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to work with the **YoutubeLiveChat-API** in Java.
I'm having trouble to insert a `LiveChatMessage` because it is always returning the errorcode 400:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.part",
    "location" : "part",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "liveChatMessage",
    "reason" : "unknownPart"
  } ],
  "message" : "liveChatMessage"
}
```

The error occurs at the following line:

```
youtube.liveChatMessages().insert("snippet,liveChatMessage",msg).execute();
```

I already know that the problem is `insert(<String>,msg)` but I don't know what to put int for String.

---

Thank you!